# How can add a value on a figure using uicontrol?

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I read and show a signal, but I would like that my program ask to the user the sampling frequency in the same figure, not in the command windows using GUI's.

After that I want to get that value for my program

Any help would be aprreciated!!!

Comment: Have you tried the `edit` uicontrol?

Comment: Yes, I have, but I am not an expert. This is my code

Comment: clc;
close all;
clear all;

 f = figure;
txtbox = uicontrol(f,'Style','edit',...
                'String','     ',...
                'Position',[30 50 130 20]);
            pause();
            S = get(txtbox, 'string')

Comment: But the problem is when I runned all the code I didn´t get the value I want in S, just when i runned first all the code except the last line and after the last line. Can you help me?

Comment: You need to have callbacks as well. See my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a callback function as well. Matlab uses functions like, `figure, axes, uicontrol, ...` to create different graphical objects. Until you determine what you want to happen with them it is impossible to interact with them though. Matlab cannot understand what you want to do with the editbox. You may for example want to type `'exit'` to close the GUI. To write instructions to Matlab GUI you can work with callback functions. There are of course other ways which are more complicated and requires (much) more code, but callback functions is a simple way to interact with figures and is the way recommended by Matlab. To keep control of the handles, you can use the function `guidata`. Below follow an example where you can use an editbox to plot a mesh graph or a surf graph. The equation is hardcoded in this example to focus on the problem stated in the question.

```
function textboxgui()

% Create GUI layout
hfig=figure();
set(hfig,'Units','normalized');
hax1 = axes('Parent',hfig);
set(hax1,'Position',[0.05,0.35,0.6,0.6]);

editbox = uicontrol(hfig,'Style','edit','Units','normalized','Position',[0.75,0.4,0.2,0.1],...
    'String','plottype','Callback',@editCallback);
% Assign all handles to the variable handles
handles = [];
handles.hfig = hfig;
handles.hax1 = hax1;
handles.editbox = editbox;
% Use guidata to be able to have access to the data in callbacks
guidata(hfig,handles);
end


function editCallback(hObject,callbackdata)
% Callback function, do a surf plot if the string is surf and a meshplot if
%the string is mesh

%Load guidata
data = guidata(hObject);
str = data.editbox.String;

code to plot surf or mesh
if strcmpi(str,'surf')
    surf(data.hax1,peaks);
elseif strcmpi(str,'mesh')
    mesh(data.hax1,peaks);
end

end
```

I should add here that if you want the value of the input you need to add it to the value property of the editbox. `data.editbox.Value = str2num(data.editbox.String)`. And to update the `guidata`, add `guidata(hObject,data)`.

Comment: thanks, it is more clear to me using callback functions,But I'm really need to study more GUI's. And yes it works how I wanted

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [inputdlg](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputdlg.html). And if you post bunch of your code, it is easier to help you.

Comment: a=load('sgnal.txt');


freq=input('Sampling Frequency: '); %Ingresar la frecuencia de muestreo de la señal
T=(1/freq):1/freq:(1/freq)*length(a);
 
a1=zeros(length(a),1);
c2=hsv(size(a,2));
for i=1:size(a,2)
    a1(:,i)=abs(a(:,i));
    subplot(5,1,i),plot(T,a1(:,i),'color',c2(i,:)),grid on,xlabel('Time [sec]'),ylabel('[V]')
    axis tight
end

Comment: This is my code, but I want that in the same figure the program asks for the samplig frequency instead of the windows command

Comment: @PepeLópez. Use freq=inputdlg('Enter Sampling Frequency:', 'Sampling Frequency');

Comment: @Lati `inputdlg` is probably the simplest way, but it may be annoying to have windows pop up every time you want to edit a property. Also, you may want to set a lot of properties and having loads of windows pop up can be an annoyance. If this is not a problem, just go for `inputdlg`.

Comment: Yes is only one value the user needs to put in the code,